# Should I send sensitive info from the server in a jwt or plain json?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, security, jwt

I have a login route that returns:

- a cookie with a jwt payload: user.id and user.locale
- a json response with a user object.

This user object contains sensitive informations such as geolocation, email, etc. This response is stored in a react global state and cached by the browser. It is never exposed in local/session storages.

Do I need to encrypt the user object in a jwt before sending it to the client? Or does it make no difference at all, and sending it in plain json will be enough?

The code looks like this:

```
const token = AuthControler.generateToken(user);
const encryptedUser = AuthControler.encryptUser(user);
    return res
      .status(200)
      .cookie("myapp", token, {
        expires: new Date(Date.now() + msPerDay * 14),
        httpOnly: true,
        secure: true
      })
      .json({ user: encryptedUser });
```

Comment: It makes no difference. As noted below, JWT does not really "encrypt" the data and is not secure. Instead, make sure you're using a HTTPS connection exclusively - that will truly encrypt ALL data sent over the wire between server and client. If you need data to be saved on the client but opaque to it (i.e. the client has no way to decrypt the data) then you would encrypt that data separately and securely by the server before transmission. If you need the data to be _secure_ but _readable by the client_, simply use HTTPS.

Comment: Thanks. So encrypting the token with bcrypt and using a https connection is better than using jwt then. But what is the purpose of jwt if a proper level of security can be achieved with a crypto library and an http-only cookie?

Comment: JWTs provide confidence that the content within them is valid, unchanged, and from who they say they're from. This is because they are cryptographically _signed_, which is not the same as being _encrypted_. A common use case would be the server providing a JWT upon login with an authorization token. The user/client cannot change the contents of the JWT because if they did, the cryptographic signing would no longer be valid. This gives the server more confidence that requests bearing that JWT are from a valid authorized user. https://jwt.io/introduction

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JSON Web Token can be decoded, even without the signing private key / signing secret - it's not encrypted on its own. See here: https://jwt.io/ - paste your JWT (having read the warnings about sensitive data) and get the user info back.

If you want to avoid exposing the data to the user, *encrypt* it (not JWT) yourself. [This technique is often applied to cookies, as well](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/67401/what-is-actually-the-purpose-of-encrypting-the-values-in-a-cookie) - e.g. to prevent fuzzing by cookies and other tampering. Alternatively, if you do maintain some kind of session state on the back-end, it's a good place to put the data and never have to send it to the client in the first place.

Last but not least, it's important that you have a threat model before setting out to implement security. What's the data that is protected? Who are you protecting against? Is e.g. "another user of the same computer" part of the model? Can the data be obtained in some other way, e.g. by actively making requests to your system? Is it affected by GDPR in any way, and if so, does it achieve minimization of data processing?

Comment: I don't maintain any session in the back end. I just have an http-only cookie that self-destroys after 14 days, and that is used to access any sensitive route. Ok, so instead of using jwt, I should rather encrypt the cookie payload with bcrypt.hashSync(), send it as http-only so no one can fetch and tamper it, and check its validity in my authentification middleware with bcrypt.compareSync(). But then, what is the purpose of jwt if I can achieve a proper auth with a crypto library and an http-only cookie? I have not identified any specific threat. I just want a good level of security.

Comment: @DoneDeal0 Nothing prevents you from using JWT + cookie encryption, and storing auxiliary data in the JWT that help your services identify the user, show them greetings (Hello, Dave!), send them notifications, etc. This way, you can provide authorization and add context at the same time, and you don't have to worry about passing a *second* value along with your token. Whether this provides "a good level of security" will entirely depend on your threat model - at some point, you'll have to do your security homework; applying "best practices" is not enough.

Answer (score 2):

Contrary to popular belief JWT tokens may come in both JWS (signed only) or JWE (truly encrypted) formats. JWE is just not a widespread capability of most JWT/JOSE libraries.

If your system is both the issuer and consumer of these tokens than you can use encrypted JWTs, e.g. using the `jose`'s package [EncryptJWT module](https://github.com/panva/jose/blob/main/docs/classes/jwt_encrypt.encryptjwt.md#readme).

The `{ alg: 'dir', enc: 'A256GCM'}` is suited for such a setup, the secret key would be a 256bit random secret. Other `enc` values may require different sized secret keys.

Resulting JWT looks like so, the only readable portion prior to decryption is the JWE Protected Header.

```
eyJhbGciOiJkaXIiLCJlbmMiOiJBMjU2R0NNIn0..dHrDXdmJIg9pwujk.ZX69BYgPmnCYpztL9BgdyaElv1wEebfq6dIrhoh6TEFiocGK4uwK6rt6pA6oXEkLd-pVVxtIaSTb6r5On1PU0EG9uqJbk7yGaMkq_OF1ZsbVbsHoGPaggoi5j7PCSLmRJdr1iByp7IJ2yWzTx-yzVgnBJgk.dSsVWFbQYLmr0mUBJVWpfQ
```

Comment: What is the most secure option between bcrypt and jose/jwt/encrypt? Also, which one is the fastest to decipher on the server? Indeed, I will need to check the data on each api call, so it must be blazing fast for an optimal user experience.

Comment: I see the resolution above to use bcrypt for signing a cookie. Don't do that to yourself, bcrypt is for one-way hashing passwords so that they're really hard to re-compute. It's very heavy on your CPU.

For a simple cookie signing scheme you could use https://www.npmjs.com/package/keygrip

Otherwise the JWE dir+A256GCM encryption is an AEAD cipher that is fast. But i'll leave that up to you to check, i mean, compare it to bcrypt and you'll see.